# .htaccess RewriteRule дублируется параметр в адресной строке

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Разбираюсь, как сделать «чистые ссылки» с помощью `.htaccess`, например `http://example.com/?alias=some-content` преобразовать в `http://example.com/some-content`.

```
[.htaccess]
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^([a-z0-9\-\_]+)$    /?alias=$1 [nc]
```

Эти настройки работают, но если переходишь в не-корневой каталог сайта, `?alias=...` появляется в адресной строке:

```
http://example.com/admin
превращается в
http://example.com/admin/?alias=admin
```

Как этого избежать?

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы если в браузера набрали _http://example.com/?alias=some-content был редирект на _http://example.com/some-content ? Или чтобы на ваших страницах ссылки сразу были вида _http://example.com/some-content ?

Comment: @Visman нужно чтоб url в браузере было `http://example.com/some-content`, а скрипт получал `$_GET['alias'] = 'some-content'`

Comment: Чтобы в браузере были ссылки вида _http://example.com/some-content, их надо в php (или на чем вы пишите) формировать такими.

Comment: А чтобы в $_GET['alias'] получать данные, надо .htaccess примерно так: RewriteEngine On
 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?alias=$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: Руководство по настройке ЧПУ (Rewrite) можно тут http://www.cyberforum.ru/apache/thread652774.html например посмотреть.

Comment: @Visman руководство лучшее из всего, что попадалось. думаю, проблема в том, что я не разобрался зачем RewriteCond и не пользовался им.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выношу правильный ответ из комментариев.

1. Во-первых, [самое понятное объяснение](http://cyberforum.ru/apache/thread652774.html) настройки `Rewrite`.
2. Второе немаловажное, добавлю от себя: не забываем **сбрасывать кэш браузера** при изменении `.htaccess`

И правильный ответ:

```
/*
** URL: http://example.com/admin 
*/

RewriteEngine On                                   // включаем преобразование
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d                // если `admin` - это не папка
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f                // если `admin` - не имя файла
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?alias=$1 [L,QSA]      // только тогда используется правило
                                                   // ключ [L] - остановить преобразование
                                                   // ключ [QSA] - передать $_GET скрипту
```